# A tool to manage housekeeping for multiple TYPO3 installs?

Tags: typo3

There used to be a tool at http://t3manager.com which had the goal to allow administrators to manage multiple TYPO3 installs to eg. get an overview over the health of extensions. It seems to have been discontinued.

What tool do you use / can be used to manage housekeeping for multiple TYPO3 installs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is also a [`caretaker`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/caretaker) + [`caretaker_instance`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/caretaker_instance) extension set, which allows to monitor many instances of TYPO3. I used it several years ago, but tbh I don't know what is its current state. I can see it's still updated.

Comment: And how do you track your extension versions? Just by logging in (like me) or do you keep a record?

Comment: TBH, I don't remember ATM, anyway if nothing changed caretaker can ask instances also for that if extensions are up to date, if TYPO3's veriosn isn't marked as a security hole, etc. You need to test it yourself

Comment: Currently I'm not using it, in most cases our clients has their admins to care about the instances (we're developers) and if we are controlling something in most cases it's on our servers just.